# What is BSE's attitude to 'Promotional' Q&A's?

Tags: discussion

A few times, I've seen questions posted, and self-answered immediately. The answers are often good, and link out to a tutorial on the subject. An example might be:

[How to create a perfect circular or elliptical motion without curves or addons?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234967/how-to-create-a-perfect-circular-or-elliptical-motion-without-curves-or-addons)

While the posts can contain useful information, they are tantamount to an advertisement for the tutorial. How should we treat these posts? Is this OK?

Comment: An answer should always stand on its own without replying on external data to fully reproduce the presented solution. If the solution cannot be fully reproduced without visiting the link,or the answers seems to exists solely for promoting a link , then it may be considered unwanted and flagged as spam.

Comment: As for addons and external downloads is a bit of a gray area. A valid answer that requires an addon or downloading some external file is possible, but ideally it should be self contained. If it is a commercial or payed product then I'd say it is a no go. For non commercial products I'd say the answer should still be substantial and present a descriptive solution. If possible transcribe the required script using code tags

Comment: @Duarte, that's kind of the way I was thinking. It's not as if BSE is becoming an Exchange and Mart for monetized videos. If the answers stand on their own, they are useful.